# Can't get back to weight paint with metarig selected

Tags: weight-paint-mode

I was trying to remove the toe bone from my metarig. But after i remove the bone, i couldn't get back to weight paint mode with the metarig selected. The steps i did was Weight Paint mode -> Object Mode -> clicks on anywhere to remove the selection -> Clicks on metarig -> Edit Mode -> removing the toe bone. After that, i couldn't get back to weight paint with the metarig selected

[image]

Before the steps

[image]

After the steps (only body is selected)

The toe bone wasn't removed yet on the screenshot because i had to retrace the steps i did, and i still don't get how can i get back to "before the steps" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object mode, select the Metarig, shift select the Model, then switch to weight paint mode (Active object = last selected has to be a mesh object in order to access weight paint mode).